# Format MySQL code inside PHP string

Tags: php, mysql, format

Is there any program IDE or not that can format MySQL code inside PHP string e.g. 
I use PHPStorm IDE and it cannot do it.

It does that for PHP and MYSQL but not for MYSQL inside php string. I am ready to use new IDE because now i have to manually format hundreds of database requests that are one line and not readable. Only criteria for my choice is that ide can do that automatically.

```
<?php
...
$request1 = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_id= {$_SESSION['admin_id']} and active= 1 order By admin_id Asc";
...
?>
```

should become

```
<?php
...
$request1 = "SELECT * 
               FROM tbl_admin 
                  WHERE admin_id = {$_SESSION['admin_id']}
                  AND active = 1
                      ORDER BY admin_id ASC";
...
?>
```

Comment: You mean you want the software to indent the code like your second example?

Comment: I believe that is the question.

Comment: Yes i do want software to automatically reformat the code.

Comment: because in php your sql query is in string format so no ID will think that it is an sql query or normal query so its not possible because ist a string for that IDE

Comment: BTW: You should urgently prevent SQL injection with prepared statements or with `mysql_real_string_escape()`.

Comment: BTW: That PHP String does not contain a valid MySQL SQL syntax, e.g. `{$_SESSION['admin_id']}` will make a SQL parser stumble upon I assume.

Comment: How can JohnA offer 300 reputation when he only has 57?

Comment: @hakre: I presume that these strings serve as templates and the string you're quoting will be replaced by something meaningful.

Comment: @chiccodoro The rep system takes away the bounty before he awards it, so he will have had 357 when he added the bounty.

Comment: @JohnA you can build my answer below into a bash script that can run through all documents you point it at to find and replace text. Things to think about are ignoring content inside of encapsulation such as () {} [] and using a dictionary list for formatting (sed -f input.file) other than that, you can run the entire thing from a command line to parse hundreds of thousands of files at once.

Comment: PHPStorm uses the Language Injection plugin for those strings: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-language-injections.html - And that plugin does not cover code-formatting right now.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to do this in my opinion is to use Regular Expressions or SED/AWK to format everything, it gives us the bonus of replacement maps on the fly. The chance that you might have code errors though is high, so it's kind of tough.

let me work on it a bit and I can see if I can come up with a good
solution. Is it guaranteed that you are encapsulating all SQL in 
double quotes?

**EDIT**

Try this

```
cd {{directory}} && find . -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 perl -i.bak -pe 's/select/SELECT/g ; s/from/\n\tFROM/g ; s/where/\n\t\tWHERE/g ; s/and/\n\t\tAND/g ; s/order by/\n\t\tORDER BY/g ; s/asc/ASC/g ; s/desc/DESC/g ;'
```

Here's an example

```
$ printf '"select * from whatever where this = that and active = 1 order by something asc";\n' |
> perl -pe 's/select/SELECT/g ; s/from/\n\tFROM/g ; s/where/\n\t\tWHERE/g ; s/and/\n\t\tAND/g ; s/order by/\n\t\tORDER BY/g ; s/asc/ASC/g ; s/desc/DESC/g ;'

"SELECT * 
    FROM whatever 
        WHERE this = that 
        AND active = 1 
        ORDER BY something ASC";
```

Is it pretty? no, not at all, does it work.... Yeup.

I'll try creating a filter file and maybe a little bash program or something as i get time to run this hot mess.

**EDIT**

Here's some revised code, looks prettier (sorta)

```
printf '$request1 = "select * from whatever where this = that and active = 1 order by something asc";\n' | 
perl -pe 's/select/SELECT/gi ; s/from/\n  FROM/gi ; s/where/\n    WHERE/gi ; s/and/\n    AND/gi ; s/order by/\n      ORDER BY/gi ; s/asc/ASC/gi ; s/desc/DESC/gi ;' | 
awk 'NR == 1 {pad = length($0)/2; print} NR > 1 {gsub(/\r/,""); printf "%*s%s\n", pad, " ", $0}'

__OUTPUTS__
$request1 = "SELECT * 
             FROM whatever 
               WHERE this = that 
               AND active = 1 
                 ORDER BY something ASC";
```

Comment: it's one step close to asking the OP to write his own Netbeans plugin.

Comment: Nope, if we were to accept the metaphor that UNIX/Linux operating systems are basically one huge IDE, then this would *actually be* a plugin (just not a Netbeans plugin).

Comment: I agree with Mihai, that this is pretty much a standalone that can parse anything its pointed at. *nix systems are pretty much there own IDE's

Answer (score 13):

As fas as I know PhpStorm can do it, if you use the heredoc syntax

```
$request1 = <<<SQL
   SELECT * 
           FROM tbl_admin 
              WHERE admin_id = {$_SESSION['admin_id']}
              AND active = 1
                  ORDER BY admin_id ASC
SQL;
```

Comment: That would mean i have to change hundreds of requests still... its very big project i got from other developer and i cannot manually change every request.

P.S. I dont want to use heredoc syntax.

Comment: If your queries don't *all* adhere to a certain syntax it's would be impossible to know if a string is SQL or not. Imagine the case where an sql string is broken over multiple lines with concatenation `'SELECT'.' * '.'FROM'`. With no strict standard everywhere guaranteeing that parameters are inserted the same way you're not going anywhere. I know heredoc is ugly but it gets the job done.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: I don't think that's entirely true.  For example, an engine could evaluate each string statement then attempt to parse for SQL; if the string contains SQL, it could backtrack to the underlying literals and format appropriately.  However, I very much doubt there's anything out there that will do this...?

Comment: @eggyal In fact PhpStorm does (something like) this. On the one hand it parses strings and compare it against known languages. This (of course) doesn't work very well for constructed strings, but works fine for example with substitution (`"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id;"`). On the other hand when you use the heredoc syntax you can give it a hint with the heredoc identifier (see `<<<SQL` above). This works quite good for continuos strings.

Comment: @eggyal PhpStorm allows you to do this provided that you use heredoc and a fixed delimiter `<<<SQL` (as @KingCrunch mentioned) **but** my point was that no editor can do this regardless of syntax. If you grab the final query you sent to the database (at runtime) and format that then look for the original string generator and find something like `SELECT <? foreach($fields AS $field): echo $field; ?>` you'll have a thrilling time formatting it.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Your example is quite simple and I promise you, that if you always write your (probably more complex) queries this way you already have at least one SQL-Injection hole. -- But yes, you are right: There is no IDE, that is able to parse such a query, but how should it format it anyway? In this format it is not even SQL, just a string with SQL-fragments.

Comment: The above was a comment not a full code example. But Implementing stuff like the Zend query builder is based on such SQL-Fragments and a lot of complex behavior depends on adding joins only if you need them. About the SQL-injection remark, you may or may not be true depending on the source of that array of field names my preferred source is a reflection API, that could not be subjected to SQL injection because property names in classes have their own validation rules that you can't brake without a fatal error.

Comment: @KingCrunch that's not to say that i'm not using prepared queries everywhere i can. But you can't parametrically change columns/tables/joins with prepared queries. You can only parametrize values. So constructing the query if you have a complex API or a framework becomes a task of aggregating various SQL fragments and using application structure (model definitions, ORMs etc) to drive SQL query builds.

Answer (score 5):

### The answer is NO.

As an alternative solution, I can suggest copying the text (ALL THE PHP CODE in the *.php file) into the query editor of [Heidisql](http://www.heidisql.com/), clicking Re-Format and copying back to NetBeans and pressing Alt+Shift+F. This will format sql and format php code after, preserving sql formatting. SO instead of a plug in, you're copying, formatting a whole file, copying back and formatting again.

Instead of HeidiSQL, you can use [this tool, which is focused on formatting](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) if you are comfortable with web tools like these.

If you want more automation, you can use regular expression support of netbeans to format with backslash n = \n for new line befre each "insert, update delete, select, where and values" terms
running this 6 times will replace all " insert" <- blank plus insert, in your projects with new lines. you can write a regular expression for searching all, "blank plus reserved word", combinations and replace them with new lines.

You can also use it like search for " insert" and repalce with "\n\t insert", which would create a new line an a tab

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Log, profile your SQL statements.
2. Use an external service such as this one - [SQLFormat API](http://sqlformat.appspot.com/api/) - in order to format your SQL statements
3. You can also run it on your machine dowloading the Python sources.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the question: Is there an IDE that will automatically format sql queries, I must concur with ugurcode. The answer is simple: there isn't any. And with good reason.

Basically an SQL query is nothing but a string in any IDE. Since strings can contain intentional whitespaces and tabs, it would be very bad if an IDE would reformat string content.

The only option that would work for any IDE would be to detect INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE at the start of a string and then format the rest of the string.. ofcourse it would also try to do the same with a string saying "insert quote here..", which once again would be a bad thing.

Since i don't want to leave you with just nothing i will give you advice on a good IDE to choose which does in fact do proper code formatting, code completion, good indentation, plugins etc.. and basically is the best IDE for php development (atleast its the best i've found in my years of professional php development).

Netbeans would be your IDE of choice. It's faster then i.e. Eclipse/PHP, more stable then i.e. codelobster etc.

Answer (score 4):

Since your problem is to format an existing body of code, you don't need an IDE. You need a script to batch-process all your files once, and then you can forget about it. This is what the script needs to do:

1. Correctly parse *PHP* strings, including strings with all sorts of embedded or escaped quotes. This should be bullet-proof, and should only care about PHP syntax.
2. Check each PHP string with an algorithm that detects SQL commands. This can be made as smart as you need it to be (no need to blindly accept every string containing the word "insert", for example).
3. Feed the identified strings through an SQL pretty-printer.
4. Edit the input file, substituting the formatted string for the original one.

Ideally, parts 1 and 3 should be handled by off-the-shelf modules. The rest should be easy to put together yourself, right?

**Update:** Explaining this made it sound so simple, I decided to do it myself. Here's a quick solution. It's in python, but if you were willing to switch IDEs you can deal with installing python, right?

Drag-and-drop any number of php files onto the script, or call it from the commandline, and it will filter the SQL bits through the [SQLFormat API](http://sqlformat.appspot.com/api/) that @Parahat suggested. It edits the files **in place**, so keep a copy!

```
"""Format sql strings embedded in php code, editing source IN PLACE"""
import sys, re, urllib, urllib2

def processfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        text = fp.read()

    with open(fname, "w") as out:
        for token in chunk(text):
            if is_sql_string(token):
                token = token[0] + sqlformat(token[1:-1]) + token[0]
            out.write(token)

def sqlformat(query):
    sqlapi = 'http://sqlformat.appspot.com/format/?keyword_case=upper&reindent=1&n_indents=4&'
    return urllib2.urlopen(sqlapi+urllib.urlencode({'data':query})).read()

php_mode = False # global, so that is_sql_string() can examine it
def chunk(src):
    """Chunk the php file into interesting units"""
    global php_mode
    while src:
        if not php_mode: # Read up to the next php group, if any
            m = re.match(r".*?<\?php", src, re.S)
            if m:
                tok, src = _usematch(m, src)
                yield tok
                php_mode = True
            else: # No more php groups: EOF
                yield src
                return

        else:  # Reading php code
            # PHP ends without another string?
            m = re.match(r"[^'\"]*?\?>", src, re.S)
            if m:
                tok, src = _usematch(m, src)
                yield tok
                php_mode = False
                continue

            # at non-string material?
            m = re.match(r"[^'\"]+", src) 
            if m:
                tok, src = _usematch(m, src)
                yield tok
                continue

            # Parse a string: Smallest quote-delimited sequence,
            # where closing quote is not preceded by backslash
            m = re.match(r'".*?(?<!\\)"|' + r"'.*?(?<!\\)'", src, re.S)
            if m:
                tok, src = _usematch(m, src)
                yield tok
                continue

            # Something I can't parse: advance one char and hope for the best
            tok, src = src[0], src[1:]
            yield tok

def _usematch(m, inp):
    return m.group(), inp[m.end():] # Matched chunk & remaining input

# To recognize an sql command, it MUST begin with one of these words
sql_commands = set("select insert update delete create drop alter declare".split())
def is_sql_string(tok):
    if not php_mode or len(tok) < 3 or tok[0] not in set("\"'"):
        return False    
    tokwords = tok[1:-1].split()
    return tokwords and tokwords[0].lower() in sql_commands

for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
    processfile(fname)
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHPStorm you can specify SQL dialect for your project: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/sql-dialects.html

Next, you must setup Data Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/data-sources-2.html

After that your IDE will support SQL syntax and autocomplete for tables (fields).

---

Also, there is a page, where you can specify SQL code-style: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/code-style-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no such IDE. 
Maybe some SQL is broken into multiple string concatenation, or maybe some SQL is generated using some iterator. Or maybe it contains invalid SQL such as `{$_SESSION['admin_id']}`.

Your only chance is writing a small script, tuned to match the coding style and possible invalid SQL stuff, which will repair all application source code files. It will take you hours to get it right, but in the end you won't need an IDE which doesn't exist, and you will have a prettyfiend stonified SQL and better source code.

(The above is a solution, thinking you have hundreds of SQL statement throughout the app; if not, just repair them by hand).

Edit: make sure you log all changes in a comparison table, so you can review all which was formatted by your script.

Comment: I doubt it will beautify some scrambled SQL. And its expensive. For 100€ I'll write that script to fix the entire project.

Comment: I only posted that link because you said in your answer, "There is no such IDE." I'd be willing to write a script for that price too. ;)

Answer (score 2):

may be nuSphere debugger somehow help you for doing this here is the link [nuSphere](http://www.nusphere.com/download.php.ide.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Write your queries in MySQL Workebench then edit->format->beautify query

Then paste the query into netbeans, select the test and tab in.

Answer (score 2):

I always used [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php) to format my SQL statements and paste them back to the IDE, because i didn't find an IDE either, which is able to format sql inside php blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I built a tool to do this for MS SQL Server and C# code.  I'd be happy to alter the tool for this purpose for a small fee.
http://www.softfrontiers.com/Downloads/ReIndenter.shtml

An hour or two of my time will save you many hours of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tokenizer`](http://sg.php.net/tokenizer) extension to write a script that would format the SQL.

The following script can be invoked from the command-line, it reads from standard input and writes to standard output. It handles both quoting styles (double or single quotes).

All strings are scanned for possible SQL grammar, based on the starting word, and line breaks are inserted before every keyword; both starting word and keywords are extensible, so go wild :)

```
<?php

$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));

function token_value($token)
{
        return is_array($token) ? $token[1] : $token;
}

function sql_format($s)
{
        if (preg_match("/^(?:select|insert|update|delete)/i", $s)) {
                // prefix newline and tab before every keyword
                return preg_replace('/\b(from|where|and|order|group by)/i', "\n\t\\0", $s);
        }
        return $s;
}

$target = '';
$i = 0; $n = count($tokens);
while ($i < $n) {
        $token = $tokens[$i];
        if ($token === '"') {
                $s = ''; ++$i;
                while ($i < $n && $tokens[$i] !== '"') {
                        $s .= token_value($tokens[$i]);
                        ++$i;
                }
                if ($i < $n) {
                        ++$i;
                }
                $target .= '"' . sql_format($s) . '"';
        } elseif (is_array($token) && $token[0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) {
                $quote_style = $token[1][0];
                $target .= $quote_style . sql_format(trim($token[1], "'\"")) . $quote_style;
                ++$i;
        } else {
                $target .= token_value($token);
                ++$i;
        }
}

echo $target;
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there any program IDE or not that can format MySQL code inside PHP string

with specifically this PHP string definition:

> ```
> $request1 = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_id= {$_SESSION['admin_id']} and active= 1 order By admin_id Asc";
> ```

And the answer is no. There doesn't exist a well use-able settop on a PHP parser in IDEs or on the commandline that works PHP's `token_get_all`.

With `token_get_all` you should be able to first of all extract that part that makes sense in your case to be edited. Here with context:

> `<309:T_VARIABLE> "$request1"  <371:T_WHITESPACE> " "  "="  <371:T_WHITESPACE> " "  """  <314:T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE> "select * from tbl_admin where admin_id= "  <375:T_CURLY_OPEN> "{"  <309:T_VARIABLE> "$_SESSION"  "["  <315:T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING> "'admin_id'"  "]"  "}"  <314:T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE> " and active= 1 order By admin_id Asc"  """  ";"`

As these tokens show,  there is a lot of additional work going to extract that what you call string from it:

> `$request1 = "select * from tbl_admin where admin_id= {$_SESSION['admin_id']} and active= 1 order By admin_id Asc"`

This need to be managed and identified in tokens:

> `<314:T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE> "select * from tbl_admin where admin_id= "  <375:T_CURLY_OPEN> "{"  <309:T_VARIABLE> "$_SESSION"  "["  <315:T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING> "'admin_id'"  "]"  "}"  <314:T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE> " and active= 1 order By admin_id Asc"`

As this example shows, this is not true SQL. So you not only need to find a SQL parser (which exists in PHP, see [Parsing sql query PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11051711/367456)), but you also need to make that SQL parser aware of PHP variable substitution like `{$_SESSION['admin_id']}` in your case. For you it is a variable, for an SQL parser this is just a freaky syntax soup if not an error.

Your small code example is a good one: It already shows that there is no information about the nature of the string that will be substituted. As this information is hidden, a SQL parser will never be able to deal with this string as something well-formed.

So to make my answer "No" more profound: Because no general tools on how to deal with multiple outcome on the higher languages level (the PHP string has multiple probably correct representations in SQL, only the author of the variable content will can tell which one is correct) that already exists, there is no general solution available.

You might want to just fire up some regular expressions on your codebase and blitzshit together an outcome you can feel happy with, and indeed the tools [ehime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124066/367456) lined-up are worth to consider.

But probably it's worth to invest the time and first extract the strings from the PHP token stream, reformat the string and then proceed outputting the result. That's something perl and regexes can't give you because they don't have the PHP tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no support in all the many IDEs for such a thing, there is a reason in most cases. Please consider prepared statements oder object wrappers for your work. I know both things can't be implemented in every system within a few minutes, but your code will become maintainable.

In short: **IDEs cant correct design errors. They just make them look nice and colored.**

Answer (score 0):

I have used PHPDesigner. i think this will be fulfill what you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but...

```
function formatSQL($txt){
    $txt = str_replace('SELECT ', "\nSELECT", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' MATCH', "\nMATCH", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' AGAINST', "\nAGAINST", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' OR ', "\nOR", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' AND ', "\n\tAND ", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' FROM ', "\nFROM", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' WHERE ', "\nWHERE", $txt);
    $txt = str_replace(' ORDER ', "\nORDER", $txt);
    return $txt;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.