# Parsing sql query PHP

Tags: php, sql, parsing

I want to parse a SQL query into an array. I could not figure out the code.

Example:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT id, login, pass FROM users WHERE id=3, login=faforty ORDER DESC LIMIT 3"';
```

and this sql query should be as follows:

```
$data = array();
$data['select'] = array('id', 'login', 'pass');
$data['from'] = array('id' => 3, 'login' => 'faforty');
$data['order'] = 'desc';
$data['limit'] = 3;
```

Query may be different.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283087/php-mysql-sql-parser-insert-and-update

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an SQL parser. http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Copy paste from [this example](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/wiki/ParserManual#simple_example):

```
<?php
  require_once('php-sql-parser.php');
  $parser=new PHPSQLParser('SELECT a FROM some_table an_alias WHERE d > 5;', true);

  print_r($parser->parsed);
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [SELECT] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [expr_type] => colref
                    [alias] => 
                    [base_expr] => a
                    [sub_tree] => 
                    [position] => 8
                )

        )

    [FROM] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [expr_type] => table
                    [table] => some_table
                    [alias] => Array
                        (
                            [as] => 
                            [name] => an_alias
                            [base_expr] => an_alias
                            [position] => 29
                        )

                    [join_type] => JOIN
                    [ref_type] => 
                    [ref_clause] => 
                    [base_expr] => some_table an_alias
                    [sub_tree] => 
                    [position] => 18
                )

        )

    [WHERE] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [expr_type] => colref
                    [base_expr] => d
                    [sub_tree] => 
                    [position] => 45
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [expr_type] => operator
                    [base_expr] => >
                    [sub_tree] => 
                    [position] => 47
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [expr_type] => const
                    [base_expr] => 5
                    [sub_tree] => 
                    [position] => 49
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: How can I get the array to SQL query?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question, as it's not related to this question/answer.

Comment: Oh yes! I did this as you suggested the answer to the above. Now I want that output array should be the query again

Comment: Hi! These days I am designing a new version of a SQL Parser for PHP 7.4 | 8.x. I will release an update with each stable change.
https://github.com/kevinoo/php-query-parser
https://packagist.org/packages/kevinoo/php-query-parser