# How to parse sql queries in php

Tags: php

what i need

```
   select column1,column2,column3 from table where  condition
```

output should be

> select column1 from table where  condition

i try to use explode

```
     print_r (explode(",",$str));
```

Output i need

Array

```
[0] => SELECT column1
[1] => from 
[2] => table
```

and so on .

but it will split into array and sql is dyanmic .

- any suggestion  is most welcome.

Comment: So your `explode()` ignores the first space, seems to work on commas as well and converts part of you string to upper-case. Curious.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/hAmGA)

Comment: i need sql select column1 from table where condition

Comment: This will take more than just using `explode()`. Have you *tried* anything else?

Comment: can php gives input select column1,column2,column3 from table where  condition

Comment: output should be  select column1 from table where condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing sql query PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051711/parsing-sql-query-php)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, run the original query with only the first field (column1)? If so, check it out [here](https://3v4l.org/iUMS1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very ugly solution :

```
$string = "select column1,column2,column3 from table where  condition";

$data1 = explode(" ",$string);
$data2 = explode(",",$data1[1]);
$data1[1] = $data2[0];
$string2 = implode($data1, " ");

print $string2;
```

Comment: sql column is dynamic it may increase/decrease

Comment: well it dont care of the number of the column here, it just takes the first element (in you example : column1)

Answer (score 1):

If the performance is not a problem you could try something like:

```
<?php
$query = 'select column1,column2,column3 from table where  condition';

preg_match('/select (.*) from/i', $query, $matches);
$columns = explode(',', $matches[1]);
var_dump($columns);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a3ea6230b8efd49f0d99288756cef4fc378975f

Comment: i need output sql query  select column1 from table where condition

Comment: @afeef I didn't undertand you. If you can try to put the expected result :)