# How to get desire format in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Suppose in text box the sting is given:

```
SELECT NAME,EMPLOYEEID, DEPARTMENT FROM EMPLOYEES E , DEPARTEMENT D WHERE E.DEPTID=D=DEPTID AND E.EMPLOYEEID='10';
```

output wants this format re-arranged accordingly

```
SELECT
     NAME,
     EMPLOYEEID,
     DEPARTMENT,
FROM
     EMPLOYEES E,
     DEPARTMENT D
   WHERE
     E.DEPTID=D=DEPTID
 AND E.EMPLOYEEID='10';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format MySQL code inside PHP string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005200/format-mysql-code-inside-php-string)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for "php format sql string" online comes up with some relevant results:

**SqlFormatter**

If you're using Composer:

```
require: {
  "jdorn/sql-formatter": "dev-master"
}
```

Then you use it as follows:

```
$sql = "<query goes here>";
echo SqlFormatter::format($sql);
```

- [Documentation](http://jdorn.github.io/sql-formatter/)
- [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/jdorn/sql-formatter)

**Similar question here on StackOverflow**

The (current) highest rated answer suggests using Regular Expressions or SED/AWK to solve the problem.

- [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005200/format-mysql-code-inside-php-string)